# XCode 3.2.3 doesn't show me the installed profiles

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

how are you all?

I'm having a problem with the new XCode and I think someone where maybe can help me to solve this out. I will really appreciate it.

This is my problem: I have an XCode project that contains about 10 different targets, each one has it own provisioning profile (com.domain.app1, com.domain.app2 ... for example). I've created this project using XCode 3.1.4 and I'm developing on it for at least 2 months and all works fine. BUT, when I install the new 3.2.3 XCode the problems does start ...

The biggest problem that I'm having is that in the targets properties, I go to build, select Debug or Distribution and when I want to select the profile for code signing for the target, XCode doesn't show me anything! Just shows me my iPhone Developer Name for debug and distribution, but it doesn't show me the installed profiles.

Also, I have a new Mac, so I had exported and imported my developer profile from the older mac to the new, by using the import/export options that the Organizer provides me.

Finally ... I have tested to generate the Distribution binary for one of the target and it was generated all right. As a test, I had changed the Bundle identifier from the plist of the target and try to build it again an then XCode shows me the signing error ... So, someway XCode is relating the targets with the rights profiles, but it doesn't gives me the possibility to select which profile I wanna use.

Another test that I have made is to generate a new Provisioning profile, download it, install it and XCode doesn't show it neither in the installed list of Provisioning profiles for code signing.

I don't know what can I do .. some one have an idea that maybe can help me to solve this out? Really, I will appreciate it a lot!

Thank you all.
Sebastian

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have checked that I have all right (I think so ..) in my Key Chain and the provisioning profiles appears in the organizer window under the Provisioning profiles option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Guys! I have found the problem ... in the target settings, I have "iPhone Simulator 3.2" in Base SDK, I changed it to "iPhone Device 3.2" and now it shows me all the available provisioning profiles that I have installed! I hope this will help somebody someday.. Thank you all anyway! I love stackoverflow!